# ME3 MP: Actual damage reduction for the N7 Typhoon?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

According to [this thread](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/440040-typhoon-damage-resistence-request-clarification/) the Typhoon fills the player's DR up to 50% minus whatever DR the player already has.

Question: is this true and if so, are there other sources confirming this? If not true, what is the real DR value then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Typhoon I does 44.4 damage uncharged then 1.5x after being ramped up(which makes it 66.6) The below was taken from the Mass effect 3 forum on a thread about weapon spec sheets. [Link](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/375480-weapons-stats-sheet-updated-for-all-balance-changes/)

> The GPSMG has a hidden, not-known-about Boolean damage modifier like
>   the PPR, which kicks in after 5 shots without RoF bonuses (takes more
>   shots, but same time if you have RoF bonuses active); the PPR, and
>   Typhoon share this mechanic, but more people know that after 2 seconds
>   the PPR does 4x damage, and after 1.5 seconds the Typhoon does 1.5x
>   damage.
>
> Damage per bullet
>
> Cold shot body damage TC off = 46.8666 * (1 + 0.275) = 59.7549 Cold
>   shot body damage TC on = 46.8666 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.8) = 97.2481 Hot
>   shot body damage TC off = 46.8666 * 1.5 * (1 + 0.275) = 89.6324 Hot
>   shot body damage TC on = 46.8666 * 1.5 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.8) = 145.8722
>
> Cold shot head damage TC off = 46.8666 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.2) * 2.5 =
>   172.8205 Cold shot head damage TC on = 46.8666 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.2 + 0.8) * 2.5 = 266.5537 Hot Shot head damage TC off = 46.8666 * 1.5 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.2) * 2.5 = 259.2308 Hot Shot head damage TC on = 46.8666 * 1.5 * (1 + 0.275 + 0.2 + 0.8) * 2.5 = 399.8307
>
> With Cryo debuff  Cold shot TC off = 46.8666 * (1 + 0.275) * (1 +
>   0.25) = 74.6936 Hot shot TC off = 46.8666 * 1.5 * (1 + 0.275) * (1 + 0.25) = 112.0404